# How to print a variable that contains unprintable characters?

Tags: shell, variable, character-encoding, special-characters

I want to display the value of the `$IFS` variable, which could contain unprintable characters (for example: newline).

I used the following command to do so:

```
echo -n "$IFS" | hexdump -C
```

Which worked great in my case.

But is there anything wrong in using this command? For example, does `echo` replaces some unprintable characters with some other characters before printing them to its `stdout`, or some other problem like that?

Comment: I'd add "cat -v" as taken from here https://www.unix.com/302465728-post4.html :
echo $variable | cat -v

Answer (score 9):

Some various approaches at giving visual representations of strings:

#### POSIX

```
$ printf %s "$IFS" | od -vtc -to1
0000000      \t  \n  \0
        040 011 012 000
0000004
$ printf '%s\n' "$IFS" | LC_ALL=C sed -n l
 \t$
\000$
```

(the extra `\n` is necessary as otherwise the behaviour of `sed` is unspecified if the last line doesn't end in a newline). A POSIX `sh` won't have NUL in `$IFS` like my zsh does here. The behaviour of `sed` is unspecified if the input contains NULs.

#### Shell builtins

- `typeset -p` (ksh, zsh, bash, yash) might give you an unambiguous output for some strings.

  ```
  $ ksh93 -c 'typeset -p IFS'
  IFS=$' \t\n'
  $ zsh -c 'typeset -p IFS'
  typeset IFS=$' \t\n\C-@'
  $ mksh -c 'typeset -p IFS'
  typeset IFS=$' \t\n'
  $ a=$'\u00e9e\u301\u200b' ksh -c 'typeset -p a'
  typeset -x a=$'\u[e9]e\u[301]\u[200b]'
  ```

  but for that latter one (using Unicode combining acute accent and zero-width space characters), zsh/mksh are not helping (even with `LC_ALL=C typeset -p a` with `mksh -o utf8-mode`). `bash`'s output is generally not unambiguous when sent to a terminal.
- `printf %q` with GNU `printf` and the `printf` builtin of `ksh93`, `zsh` and `bash`:

  ```
  $ a=$'\u00e9e\u301\u200b' bash -c 'printf "%q\n" "$IFS" "$a" ""'
  $' \t\n'
  éé​
  ''
  $ a=$'\u00e9e\u301\u200b' ksh -c 'printf "%q\n" "$IFS" "$a" ""'
  $' \t\n'
  $'\u[e9]e\u[301]\u[200b]'
  ''
  \ $'\t'$'\n'$'\0'
  éé​
  ''
  $ a=$'\u00e9e\u301\u200b' sh -c '/usr/bin/printf "%q\n" "$IFS" "$a" ""'
  ' '$'\t\n'
  éé​
  ''
  $ a=$'\u00e9e\u301\u200b' zsh -c 'LC_ALL=C printf "%q\n" "$IFS" "$a" ""'
  \ $'\t'$'\n'$'\0'
  $'\303'$'\251'e$'\314'$'\201'$'\342'$'\200'$'\213'
  ''
  $ a=$'\u00e9e\u301\u200b' bash -c 'LC_ALL=C printf "%q\n" "$IFS" "$a" ""'
  $' \t\n'
  $'\303\251e\314\201\342\200\213'
  ''
  ```
- `q`, `qq`, `qqq`, `qqqq` parameter expansion flags in `zsh`.

  for various types of quoting, `qqqq` being the one for `$'...'`:

  ```
  $ a=$'\u00e9e\u301\u200b' zsh -c 'print -r -- ${(qqqq)a}'
  $'éé​'
  $ a=$'\u00e9e\u301\u200b' zsh -c '(){local LC_ALL=C; print -r -- ${(qqqq)a}}'
  $'\303\251e\314\201\342\200\213'
  ```

  There's also `q` and `q+` that only uses quoting for things that *need* it (though still with the caveat for those unicode ones).

### various non-standard commands:

- hex-dumper: `hexdump`, `hd`, `xxd`... You'd want to feed them the output of `printf %s "$var"` (or `print -rn -- "$var"` with ksh/zsh, or `echo -nE - "$var"` with `zsh`...).
- `cat -vte` or `cat -A`
- `uconv -x hex` for unicode code points of characters (as opposed to hex value of the bytes of the encoding), only for UTF-8 (one can preprocess the input with `iconv -t utf-8` though provided it's valid text in the locale's encoding)
- `uconv -x name` for the character names
- `recode ..dump`. both hex and name but know about fewer Unicode characters (not updated with newer versions of Unicode). Works in non-UTF-8 locales though.

Answer (score 7):

Especially with `IFS`, you absolutely want to quote it, since otherwise it, well turns to nothing. You did that already, so no problem there.

As for `echo`, it depends on the shell. Some versions of `echo` handle backslash-escapes by default, some don't. Bash's doesn't, zsh's does:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "foo\nbar"'
foo\nbar
$ zsh -c 'echo "foo\nbar"'
foo
bar
```

It's better to use `printf` instead: `printf "%s" "$IFS" | hexdump -C`.

See also: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/170373)

`printf "%q" "$IFS"` also works in Bash and zsh.

That should keep you fine, except that Bash can't handle NUL bytes (`\0`) at all, zsh can. Bash:

```
$ var=$'foo\0bar'
$ printf "%q\n" "$var"
foo
```

zsh:

```
$ var=$'foo\0bar'
$ printf "%q\n" "$var"
foo$'\0'bar
```

Comment: (Not that I've ever tried to just `echo $IFS`. Never. I should know better.)

Answer (score 4):

The only character that doesn't work in bash is the null.

```
$ var="$(perl -wE 'print map chr, 0 .. 255')"
$ echo -n "$var" | xxd
0000000: 0102 0304 0506 0708 090a 0b0c 0d0e 0f10  ................
0000010: 1112 1314 1516 1718 191a 1b1c 1d1e 1f20  ............... 
0000020: 2122 2324 2526 2728 292a 2b2c 2d2e 2f30  !"#$%&'()*+,-./0
0000030: 3132 3334 3536 3738 393a 3b3c 3d3e 3f40  123456789:;<=>?@
0000040: 4142 4344 4546 4748 494a 4b4c 4d4e 4f50  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
0000050: 5152 5354 5556 5758 595a 5b5c 5d5e 5f60  QRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
0000060: 6162 6364 6566 6768 696a 6b6c 6d6e 6f70  abcdefghijklmnop
0000070: 7172 7374 7576 7778 797a 7b7c 7d7e 7f80  qrstuvwxyz{|}~..
0000080: 8182 8384 8586 8788 898a 8b8c 8d8e 8f90  ................
0000090: 9192 9394 9596 9798 999a 9b9c 9d9e 9fa0  ................
00000a0: a1a2 a3a4 a5a6 a7a8 a9aa abac adae afb0  ................
00000b0: b1b2 b3b4 b5b6 b7b8 b9ba bbbc bdbe bfc0  ................
00000c0: c1c2 c3c4 c5c6 c7c8 c9ca cbcc cdce cfd0  ................
00000d0: d1d2 d3d4 d5d6 d7d8 d9da dbdc ddde dfe0  ................
00000e0: e1e2 e3e4 e5e6 e7e8 e9ea ebec edee eff0  ................
00000f0: f1f2 f3f4 f5f6 f7f8 f9fa fbfc fdfe ff    ...............
```

`printf` is more portable then `echo`, but for my system and shell (bash), their output is exactly the same.

```
printf %s "$var"
```

Comment: I would additionally opt for `printf '%s' "$var"` rather than `echo -n` (for portability).

Comment: Try with `var=-e`

Answer (score 2):

I love the `Q` parameter transformation operator in Bash:

```sh
echo "${IFS@Q}"
```

Output:

```
$' \t\n'
```

This `$'string'` quoting is called [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

The `Q` operator can also be used to pass parameters to commands with SSH:

```sh
f='filename with space'
ssh "$host" "ls -l ${f@Q}"
```

The [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) section has the list of all operators. The `A` operator is also useful:

```bash
a=(array with 'various elements')
echo "${a[@]@A}"
```

Output:

```
declare -a a=([0]="array" [1]="with" [2]="various elements")
```

Comment: just to note that @Q appears in bash 4, so default version of bash in macOS (3.2) fails to parse it. if you need it, upgrading bash using brew helps